# Which sharelatex theme is most similar to texmaker's default?

Tags: texmaker, sharelatex

Just started using sharelatex for the compiling boost, and the theme they use is throwing me off, because I very much used the default colour scheme used in texmaker for highlighting text to spot errors.

Which theme for sharelatex is the most similar to texmaker's default one?

Comment: Can't you use different schemes with TeXmaker as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh dear, that complicates things, I'll just have to check which one I use then

Comment: Wait, i am not sure. Maybe it is texmaker that supports different schemes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Johannes_B As far as I can tell there is a dark theme, a default theme, and you can manually edit the colours if you wish, I just use default though, but I'll add that to the question